# First Angular app, need help creating an input form/list, maintain list,not showing on page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on my first angular app and I wanted to build a quick site where friends to add their name to a list.  I was able to get the form / list created but I'm not sure how to make sure that the data is retained. I was trying to find a way to send to a text file or an array somewhere but not sure how that part is created.
Again, I'm new and looking for a way to get started.

I have created a Plunker preview to help illustrate my issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/oUygsUnoKKJgL4FI1rFV?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.7" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    form {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController" class="container">

    <form name="satellite" class="form-horizontal">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.Name" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="add if not on email list" ng-model="item.Email" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prefered Date:</td>
          <td>
            <input placeholder="mm/dd" ng-model="item.Date" name="date" ng-pattern='/^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))/' />
            <span ng-show="satellite.date.$error.pattern">Incorrect Format, should be MM/DD</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <input type="Button" value="Add" ng-click="addItem(item)" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <br />
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td width="150">Name</td>
          <td>Prefered Date</td>
          <td>Email Address</td>
          <td>Remove Item</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Email}}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="removeItem($index)" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```js
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])

.controller('formController', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.addItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.push(item);
    $scope.item = {};
  }
  
  $scope.getTotalPlayers = function() {
    return $scope.items.length;
  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  function MyCtrl($scope) {}

});
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed.  I have copied the code from the Plunker to my Gmail drive and tested but again, every time I add a name and close the browser and return to page, all data is lost.

Hopefully this is an easy one.

Cheers,

Comment: actually that is the expected behavior. Javascript running from a browser has very limited capability to save data. If you need data persistence then you need to submit the data to the server and handle saving of data there. Alternatively you can save data on client machine using cookies and in modern browser using local storage. But saving on client machine means that when you log in from another machine the data would be lost.

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you have a recommendation on how to improve the list to operate in the manner I was hoping for?  Is there a way to push the form input to a file?  Sorry for such a basic question, but I'm new to the process and hoping to start learning more about web development.

Comment: I believe I have found an option but the only post I can find are about pulling data from Google Docs but not writing to Google Docs.  Here is an example of what I found: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-google-doc-spreadsheet-serve-json-from-excel-spreadsheet/  I believe this is a good concept, just need to figure out how to write to the sheet.